# Child div having position:relative causing problems

Tags: css, d3.js, css-position, c3.js

I have a dropdown menu which is as follows:

[image]

It works on other pages just fine, but on this page, there's a c3 chart which has `position: relative;` in it's class definition, and I don't know how to change it (it is loaded straight from their api). This causes the dropdown to disappear if hovered so low that one reaches the chart's div.

If I change it from 'relative' to 'static' in chrome developer console, it works just fine. Is there something wrong with my dropdown .css? Or is there a way to simply overwrite the position: relative?

```
  li a, .dropbtn {
    color: white;
  }

  li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #333;
  }

  li.dropdown {
    display: block;
    float: right;
  }
  li.dropdown:hover {
    display: block;
    float: right;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `z-index: 9999` to your `.dropdown-content` class. Does that do anything?

Also, add `position: relative` to your `li`. You need the dropdown to know what parent it is attached to (since it is `position: absolute`). When you do this, you may need to adjust the `top` and `left`, likely to `top: 100%; left: 0` based on your width.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I assume it makes .dropdown-content highest in "hierarchy", and that's why ignores all for example, the position:relative?

Comment: Something like that, when you have multiple `position: relatives`, it has to know when to render on that third axis, the "z" axis. All you're doing is layering it, but it helps. I've run into that issue many times with absolute/relative positioning.

Also, I've updated my answer with another helpful piece if you're interested regarding that positioning.